# WPF компоновка (запрет на изменение размера фрэймов)

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

В технологии WPF в окне производится разметка (с помощью элементов Grid), после чего создаются Фрэймы для дальнейшего расположения элементов. Какое свойство отвечает за блокировку изменения размера определенного фрэйма при изменении размеров окна?

Comment: Фреймы плохо. А размеры - задайте ячейке грида строгие размеры да и все.

Comment: `Какое свойство отвечает за блокировку изменения размера определенного фрэйма при изменении размеров окна?` - высота и ширина, задайте явно, и размер  не будет меняться. Но то что вы спрашиваете, звучит очень странно. Располагать элементы надо в XAML, а для их группировки использовать панели (`Grid`, `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, ...). А для отображения коллекций `ListBox`, `ItemsControl`, `ListView`, `DataGrid`, и т.д, привязыаясь к данным через `ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"`.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы при изменении размеров приложения, один фрэйм с его содержимым никак не изменялся, а другие меняли свой размер по мере изменения размера приложения, разметка используется - Grid, область разделена на фрэймы

Comment: Вы умеете `Grid` разбивать на строки и колонки? `RowDefinitions` и `ColumnDefonitions` если нет, то научитесь, это суперпросто. Для строк и колонок можно задавать высоту и ширину, в долях, пикселях и по ширине контента.